# Validation of the MVC5 View Model does not reach the controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.Net MVC5 project, where when using the requires attribute on the ViewModel, I cannot reach my controller in the event of an invalid ViewModel. But, it only happens on a specific screen.

I need that, even with my wrong VM, this request reaches my controller, so that another action takes place in my View (in this case, a spinner is hidden).

An example of my codes:

ViewModel:

```
public class ParameterizationViewModel 
{

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of Parameterization.
        /// </summary>

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "LabelErrorFieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourcesGSC.Language))]
        [Display(Name = "LabelName", ResourceType = typeof(ResourcesGSC.Language))]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ParameterizationController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            var model = new ParameterizationViewModel();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                //Code omitted
                //Here, I structure my model to be a clean view
            }
            else
            {
                //Code omitted
                //Here, I structure my model to be a screen filled with recovered data
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ParameterizationViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Here, I validate my ViewModel. I need you to get here, but it doesn't. 
                return View(model);
            }
            //Code omitted
            //Here, follow the flow of persistence with WebService
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model Project.Models.Parameterization.ParameterizationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = ResourcesGSC.Language.LabelParameterizationMenu;
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Parameterization", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
                @ResourcesGSC.Language.LabelBtnSave
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I can't understand what happens. I have the same code in several other parts, which work perfectly.

I've searched through everything I got and I can't solve it...

Someone can help on this issue?

In addition, the validation message is displayed on the screen. But I can't get to my controller, as it happens on other screens

Comment: So valid VM's do make it to your controller? Is it the client-side validation that you don't want?

Comment: Yes, if my VM is valid it reaches my controller. 

I don't know how to explain it exactly to you. Client-side validation occurs, but I need it to reach my controller first.

I think I can say that I don't want something like Fail Fast Validation, which in my opinion is what's happening ...

I don't know if it makes sense to you, but I can try to explain it better if you get confused.

Comment: Can you try adding `HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;` to your view (under the `ViewBag.Title` part should be fine) and see if it gets the results you are expecting?

Comment: It's working!! Thx zgood !!! Could you explain to me why? I have so many other View's in my project, that I didn't have to do that and works as expected. Only this view got me into trouble ..

Comment: Missed out by 3 minutes...lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the client-side validation is getting in your way when you don't want it to. By default, if you use the MVC boilerplate code it will automatically setup and turn on client-side validation for your forms. This will validate things like required fields on the client-side in javascript and prevent the form from posting to the server if it doesn't pass this client-side validation.

You can read how it works here: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/23/manually-use-mvc-client-side-validation/ (this article tell how to manually use it, but does a good job explaining how it works)

But if you want to handle all validation server-side in your controller, you can disable the client-side validation a few ways:

- Remove the script references to `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your bundle config
- add `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>` and `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/>` to your weeb.config under the `<appSettings>` node
- Add `HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;` and `HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false;` to individual views or actions

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery validator. It will check for validation error(s) and won't let the request reach your controller in case validation fails. Since you said that client side validation is happening, I can only guess that this is the case. Disable jQuery validator and even if your view model is not valid the request will reach the controller.

If you have used default template of mvc 5 project then look for it in bundle.config file. There you can comment it out.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay!! Your answer is also correct. However, zgood added a more complete answer that could help more people in the future. Thank you anyway!